# How can i change my code about c language

Tags: c

The purpose I want to achieve is to shift these numbers to the right, but there is always a bit in the process of implementation that is a garbled problem, I want to solve this problem, please help me point it out, thank you very much.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main(void) {
    int limit, tranfer, arr[N];
    int i;
    scanf_s("%d %d", &limit, &tranfer);
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    //怎样实现来进制来向前后移动呢？  -- 循环
    int j, t;
    for (j = 0; j <(limit - tranfer); j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            t = arr[i];// 利用那个交互两个数值的思想
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = t;        
        }
          
    }
     //问题：少了数组的最后一位则应该是添加 \0 来表示结束
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

My compilation results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GpGK.png)

The result of the request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li0Xm.png)

Comment: `arr[i+1]` that will overflow the buffer on the last iteration as it will access `arr[limit]` which is not a valid index.

Comment: It's because in the last loop iteration, `arr[i+1]` is accessing out of bounds array element.

Answer (score 1):

In following loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    t = arr[i];// 利用那个交互两个数值的思想
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = t;        
}
```

when `i == limit-1` (last iteration) you swap last array element (`arr[limit-1]`) with an undefined one behind the last (`arr[limit]`), causing strange output. To solve that you just need to change your loop condition to `i < limit - 1`. Final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main(void) {
    int limit, tranfer, arr[N];
    int i;
    scanf_s("%d %d", &limit, &tranfer);
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    //怎样实现来进制来向前后移动呢？  -- 循环
    int j, t;
    for (j = 0; j <(limit - tranfer); j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < limit - 1; i++) {
            t = arr[i];// 利用那个交互两个数值的思想
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = t;        
        }
      
    }
     //问题：少了数组的最后一位则应该是添加 \0 来表示结束
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know what my problem is, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcpy() for increase performance on big array
with offset of rotate count like this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10

int main(void) {
    int limit, tranfer, arr[N];
    int i;
    scanf("%d %d", &limit, &tranfer);
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    
    int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);
    memcpy(&tmp[tranfer], arr, sizeof(int) * (limit - tranfer));
    memcpy(&tmp[0], &arr[limit - tranfer], sizeof(int) * (tranfer));
    
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("%d ", tmp[i]);
    }
    


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, a little complicated, but I'm sure I'll understand your thoughts soon, thank you brother